# Readline bindings not working with Control and Shift modifiers

Tags: bash, terminal, readline, inputrc

I'm tweaking with GNU Readline's key bindings in Bash. Specifically, I wish to achieve the following mapping effect:

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> `==>` `'I'`

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> `==>` `"I"`

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> `==>` `` `I` ``

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> `==>` `[I]`

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> `==>` `{I}`

where `I` indicates the cursor position after expansion.

I have tried the following configuration in my `~/.inputrc`. However, only the `` <C-`> `` mapping works as expected:

```
$include /etc/inputrc
$if mode=emacs
"\C-\'": "\'\'\C-b"
"\C-`": "``\C-b"
"\C-\"": "\"\"\C-b"
"\C-{": "{}\C-b"
"\C-[": "[]\C-b"
$endif
```

I'm wondering what is wrong with my configuration and how to make these mappings correctly (if possible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a terminal, you generally cannot get *all* combinations of control- and shift-modifiers to be different values:

- the basis for *control* and *shift* is from US-ASCII (and similar) schemes which defines *control* and *shift* for the alphabetic characters plus a *few* punctuation characters.
- the combination *control+shift* usually has no effect, except for *special* keys.
- some terminals define escape sequences for control/shift with *special* keys (such as cursor- and function-keys).  The <kbd>tab</kbd> key is not one of those keys.

Here is a screenshot to illustrate the control characters using ASCII:

[image]